# different initialization different outputs and different behaviour

Tags: arrays, initialization, overriding

### In this code, the values of previously accessed arrays(price, distance) were overwritten by the newly accessed array(stock) why this is happening???

But if we initialize the variables like this mentioned below then the problem solves please explain the logic behind it

{
int n;

printf("Enter the no. of products\n");

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

int i,j=0,price[n],distance[n],stock[n],final_price[n];

........code continues.......
}

--------------------------------------------main code starts here---------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

int n,i,j=0,price[n],distance[n],stock[n],final_price[n];

```
printf("Enter the no. of products\n");
scanf("%d",&n);


//Receiving and printing the price of products


printf("Enter the price of products\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&price[i]);
printf("Price:");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d,",price[i]);

//Receiving and printing the distance of products

printf("\nEnter the distance of products\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&distance[i]);
printf("Distance:");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d,",distance[i]);

//Receiving and printing the stock of products

printf("\nEnter the stock of products\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&stock[i]);
printf("stock:");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d,",stock[i]);

//final output

printf("Price:");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d,",price[i]);

printf("Distance:");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d,",distance[i]);


    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please try to be more specific, and direct about where your problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.